# Kendo React Grid inside Popout window: why getComputedStyle returns null for IE11 & Edge, but not for Chrome, Opera and Firefox?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, kendo-react-ui

I have put together [a stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ejq6dj-rxhcwk?file=app%2Fmain.js) where I am trying to render a [Kendo React Grid](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-react-ui/components/grid/) inside a  [react-popout-component](https://github.com/Microsoft/react-popout-component), which is a popout window component. The demo works fine in Chrome, Opera and Firefox, but fails in Edge and IE11, because a getComputedStyle is returning null.

The error occurs in the following file:

```
node_modules\@progress\kendo-react-grid\dist\es\header\Header.js
```

And more precisely in the following function:

```
Header.prototype.componentDidMount = function () {
    this.setState({});
    var scrollbarWidth = (new BrowserSupportService()).scrollbarWidth;
    var rtl = this.element && (getComputedStyle(this.element).direction === 'rtl') || false;
    var padding = Math.max(0, scrollbarWidth - 1) + 'px';
    var right = rtl ? 0 : padding;
    var left = rtl ? padding : 0;
    this.divStyle = { padding: "0 " + right + " 0 " + left };
};
```

In IE11 and Edge, getComputedStyle(this.element) returns null for the grid header (k-grid-header).

I must confess that I am lost :)

Answer (score 0):

There is an already logged issue in our public GitHub repo which you probably already track:

- https://github.com/telerik/kendo-react/issues/200